# In Django, how to render both JSON data with api and info from context dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

In Django, I want to render a page that includes a Chart js chart that relies on data from my database. I believe I need to implement an API for this. The same page with the chart will contain other info from the database that I think is rendered with a context dictionary and {{ variable }}. I know how to do one or the the other, but not both on the same page. Here is what I have so far. In views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Article
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        articles = Article.objects.all()

        correlationlist = []
        nocorrelationlist = []

        for corr in articles:
            if corr.correlation_type == "Correlation":
                correlationlist.append(1)
                nocorrelationlist.append(0)

            elif corr.correlation_type == "No Correlation":
                correlationlist.append(0)
                nocorrelationlist.append(1)

            else:
                pass


        correlation_items =  correlationlist
        nocorrelation_items = nocorrelationlist

        data = {
            "correlation_items": correlation_items,
            "nocorrelation_items": nocorrelation_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

The Javascript I have on the page where the chart appears is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/'
    var defaultData1 = []
    var defaultData2 = [];


    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: endpoint,
      success: function(data){
      defaultData1 = data.correlation_items
      defaultData2 = data.nocorrelation_items
      setChart()
      },

      error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
      }
     })



    function setChart(){

    CHART js code goes here

    }

})
```

But on the page where the chart appears, I also want to include other information from the data base, such as:

```
The title of the article is: {{ title }}
```

To do this and to render the page, I think I need to create a function in views as follows:

```
def results(request):
    myresults = Article.objects.all()
    context = {'myresults': myresults}
    return render(request, 'my_page_with_results_and_chart.html', context)
```

In short, how do you render a page that pulls data from an API for a chart, but also gets database information from the render(request, 'page.html', context) method? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: You need to render the page first, then access the chart data api from ajax. In this case you will have one function for rendering and another api class for chart data in views.py

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you're asking, seems very ambiguous. From a glance it looks like, myresults = Article.objects.all() and articles = Article.objects.all() are the same and you just want to get the title from the article?

Just add articles into your data dictionary

data = {
            "myresults": articles,
            "correlation_items": correlation_items,
            "nocorrelation_items": nocorrelation_items,
        }

then just reference it in your html. You cant just do {{ title }} though like your example as 'title' is not a key to your dictionary. if 'articles' is a dictionary with title as a key, you'll need to do {{ myresults.title }} in the html. I hope i answered your question :/

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking as it seems too basic but just from your examples it looks like you are..? Anyway if you do need to make an api the Django RESTful library is really good and great documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/